# Flex: Error #2038: File I/O Error

Tags: apache-flex, upload

I have a flex app doing multiple file upload, and keep getting this error:
Error #2038: File I/O Error

Flex gives this error, yet it seems to work because the upload does get processed.
This was happening intermittently, now on every attempt. Any ideas on what might be going on here? I've checked that permissions are read/write, google'd something about a trailing slash issue with the url. I'm at a loss as to what could be going on.

Comment: Can you please show a source code were this error appears?

Comment: you can dump this question. friggin cache.

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that "cleared the cache comment"? What cache are you talking about? You know you could answer your own question, and then accept that answer, so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: Any chance you're using a HTTPS link with a self-signed cert? That's caused the error #2038 for me

Comment: I also got same error, but for me was caused by slow network speed!

Answer (score 5):

Are you using an SSL certificate on the server you're uploading to?
I've had issues in the past where the Flash Player will randomly fail due to an invalid SSL certificate...

Cheers

Comment: are there any workarounds for issue with self-signed certs?

Comment: Not as far as I know, I'm afraid - sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to look at the trafic using a tool like [charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). That might give you a better indication of what really goes wrong.

It's also good to know that the Flash player with uploads forgets to send some cookies, this can cause your session at the server to be different.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just had this problem, and I did use Charles to debug the session.  Flash is just being stupid.  The response was a normal 302 response, but Flash decided to throw an IOErrorEvent anyway (in addition to the HTTPStatusEvent).  The only thing I could figure to do was search for Error #2038 in the IOErrorEvent handler and ignore events that match that pattern.  Thanks for nothing, Adobe!

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that the url to connect to the server isn't correct.  Check to see if it is a relative URL, and if so, fully qualify it.  I have found this bahavior myself...and the code can work in IE but not in other browsers, not on the Mac, not on Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem during file upload some 3-4 months before.
The call was going to servlet but in the front end i was getting some error (#2038).

Later i found out that my code was having some exception in Servlet and then it was not getting processed correctly. I does not remember what the exception was, but when i solved that exception, the error was gone.

b/w are you using commons-file-upload to upload the file?

Regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to concurrent connections that are supported. I think its 3 or 5, not sure. Are you getting the error when you attempt to upload more than 3 files?