# IO: Error #2038 jquery uploadify

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, uploadify

The code is working on one server but isn't on the other. When trying to upload files of size around 1 MB with jquery uploadify I get this error.

```
IO: Error #2038
```

Tried changing the following php settings in php.ini:

```
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
max_input_time 14400
max_execution_time 14400
memory_limit 128M
```

Isn't working.

Comment: Any chance you're using a HTTPS link with a self-signed cert? That's caused the error #2038 for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex: Error #2038: File I/O Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545715/flex-error-2038-file-i-o-error)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with flash plugins,which browser uses to upload any file.If you need more here is a link.maybe it can help you.

http://help.axletreemedia.com/templates/System/details.asp?id=31606&PG=resources&CID=34053

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

In my office, we use a proxy, and I had to change the preference to No Proxy. This solved the problem.

Or, if you do not use a proxy, try to find this in `php.ini`:

Change:

`Hostname:Port localhost:0`

To:

`Hostname:Port localhost:80`

Answer (score 0):

firefox + flash = IO: Error #2038

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/1116/io-error-2038-in-firefox-only-not-solved/p1

Answer (score 0):

**Update flash**.
the older version of flash I had, with multiple uploads would error on the every-other regardless of the file-size. I just got 10.3.181.34 which is fine-fine-fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the uploadify AJAX response does not have temporary file name.
This happens may be because of the upload filesize limitation on the server.
Try looking to server configuration.

Comment: Try explaining what the OP have to look exactly in the configuration.