# IO Error when trying to upload multiple file using uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify, ioerror

I am using jquery uploadify to upload files. It works fine on my local server but i get the error IO Error when i try to upload even the small sites in live.

Can any one please help me on this issue? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please quote the *exact error message* and the exact point at which you get it.

Comment: Where's this error coming from? Uploadify itself? Your server's error logs? Not enough details to work with.

Comment: IO Error - 2008 silver kawasaki ninja zx6r.jpg - 7.7KB/s
This is the exact form. When i choose select files and then press start upload. Every thing works well. And it shows the status bar and when the status bar reach 100% it displays the above mentioned error.

IO Error - file_name - 7.7KB/s

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the upload folders have all the right permissions? Thats one place I would check for io error with uploadify. 
Also does the script work without uploadify?

Yeah I remembered I already answered such [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265058/io-error-2038-jquery-uploadify)
There is a link in there to more help.

Comment: Yes i have given 777 permission to the folder in which i want images to be uploaded.

Comment: You should post some code then. Especially where you initiate uploadify.