# Flash Upload IOError #2038 after successful server processing

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I built two flash uploaders using actionscript 3 & actionscript 2 that sends files to a java servlet. The java servlet successfully receives that file, but the flash uploader fires an IOerror #2038 instead of a complete event.

There was another question is my exact same problem, but the answer "clear the cache" was very broad, and the question owner was too lazy to give a detailed description. If anyone could give a more detailed answer, it would very beneficial. Thanks.

[Flex: Error #2038: File I/O Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545715/flex-error-2038-file-i-o-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks alemay for your answer. It wasn't quite the problem that was experiencing. I found the answer after ALOT of digging and now I want to contribute it back so that people can just find the answer quickly.

It turns out that Amazon has a sample flash uploader that takes cares of a lot of problem flash experiences across browsers:

http://dev.nuclearrooster.com/2008/04/05/uploading-with-a-filereference-from-flex-3-on-os-x/

From that link, there are two links to Amazon directly where you can download the code.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1) The server should be returning an HTTP 200 - the Flash Player often times doesn't recognize success without one.

2) The HTTP response should contain something. An empty space, success=true, anything at all. I've had problems in the past when the response was empty.