# Issue with image upload using as and php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, image-upload

I have a button in flash as3 that uses a class to upload an image and then display it on the main movie.

I have a herarchy:

- www.MYSITE.com/test/
- www.MYSITE.com/test/uploads/
- www.MYSITE.com/test/uploads/images/

and a file called image.php
in www.MYSITE.com/test/uploads/image.php

```
<?PHP
$target_path = $_REQUEST[ 'path' ];
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'name' ] ); 

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $target_path ) ) 
{
     echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'name' ] ) . " has been uploaded;";
} 
else
{
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

The  as is:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.system.*;

    import src.events.*;
    import src.image.*;
    import src.file.*;
    import src.load.*;
    import src.ui.*;
    import com.senocular.display.transform.*

    public class ImageUploader extends Sprite 
    {
        private var m_basePath  : String = 'http://www.MYSITE.com/test/';           // web server path
        private var m_uploadPath : String = 'uploads/';                                                 // folder on server where you will allow images to be uploaded it has folder permissions  set to 777 );
        private var m_outputPath : String = 'output/';                                                  // folder on server where images should be created; folder permissions are set to 777 );

        public function ImageUploader () 
        {
            // allow script access;
            Security.allowDomain( 'http://www.MYSITE.com/test' );           
            Security.allowInsecureDomain( 'http://www.MYSITE.com/test' );   

        // determine whether the swf is being accessed from the web orlocal hard drive;
            m_isLocal = false;

            init();
        }

        // display items;
        public var upload : UIButton;                       // upload button on .fla stage;

        // output container;
        private var m_output : Sprite = new Sprite();       // container for image;
        private var m_mask : Sprite = new Sprite();         // mask for image container;
        private var m_progress : Sprite = new Sprite();     // upload / download indicator;
        private var m_effect : Scribble;                    // covers image with random effect;

        // vars;
        private var m_isLocal : Boolean;                    // determines if swf is on web server or local drive;
        private var m_fileMgr : FileManager;                // manages the opening & upload of local files;
        private var m_imagePHP : String = 'image.php';      // file that will manage image upload on your server;
        private var m_finalImage : String;                  // final name of file on creation;
        private var m_imageQuality : Number = 90;           // jpeg or png export quality;
        private var m_capture : Sprite;                     // set this equal to the sprite or movie clip that you wish to capture ( set to stage for entire movie );
        private var m_downloader : GraphicLoader;           // handles image download ( after upload is complete );
        private var m_imageExtension : String = '.jpg';     // jpeg image extension;

//      returns upload php file path based on whether or not the swf is a local publish or hosted on a web server;  
        public function get uploadPath () : String
        {
            return m_basePath + m_imagePHP;
        }

//      returns image creation php file path based on whether or not the swf is a local publish or hosted on a web server;  
        public function get createPath () : String
        {
            return m_basePath + m_imagePHP;
        }

        //returns image creation php file path based on whether or not the swf is a local publish or hosted on a web server;    
        public function get downloadPath () : String
        {
            return m_basePath + m_uploadPath;
        }

        //returns image creation php file path based on whether or not the swf is a local publish or hosted on a web server;    
        public function get finalImagePath () : String
        {
            return m_basePath + m_outputPath + m_finalImage + m_imageExtension;
        }

        //returns container for image capture container;
        public function get captureContainer () : Sprite
        {
            return m_capture;
        }

        //sets container for image capture container;
        public function set captureContainer ( inContainer : Sprite ) : void
        {
            m_capture = inContainer;
        }

        //  browse for image files on click of upload button;   
        private function onBrowse ( e : MouseEvent ) : void
        {
            m_fileMgr.browse();
        }

        //track image upload progress;
        private function onUploadProgress ( e : CustomEvent ) : void
        {
            trace( 'image uploading : ' + e.params.percent );

            m_progress.scaleX = e.params.percent;
        }

        //fires when image upload is complete;      
        private function onImageUploaded ( e : CustomEvent ) : void
        {           
            var dPath : String = String( downloadPath + e.params.fileName );

            trace( 'image ready for download at : ' + dPath );

            m_downloader.loadURL( dPath );
        }

        //track image download progress;        
        private function onDownloadProgress ( e : CustomEvent ) : void
        {
            trace( 'image downloading : ' + e.params.percent );

            m_progress.scaleX = 1 - e.params.percent;
        }

        //fires on image download is complete;      
        private function onImageDownloaded ( e : CustomEvent ) : void
        {
            trace( 'image downloaded' );

            // get image from loader;
            var clip : * = new Bitmap( e.params.loaded.bitmapData.clone() ) ;

            // add the image to the stage;
            MovieClip(parent).textAssets.text_front.txtMc.holder_clipart.x = 215;
            MovieClip(parent).textAssets.text_front.txtMc.holder_clipart.clipart.clipart_inside.inside.addChild(clip);

            if (MovieClip(parent).textAssets.text_front.txtMc.holder_clipart.clipart.clipart_inside.inside.numChildren > 0)
            {
                MovieClip(parent).textAssets.text_front.txtMc.holder_clipart.clipart.clipart_inside.inside.removeChildAt(0);
            }           

            clip.smoothing = true;

        }

        //fires if there is an error during upload;     
        private function onUploadError ( e : CustomEvent ) : void
        {
            trace( 'upload error' );
        }

        //fires if there is an error during download;       
        private function onDownloadError ( e : ErrorEvent ) : void
        {
            trace( 'download error' );
        }

        //downloads image to swf;
        private function onGetCapturedImage ( e : MouseEvent ) : void
        {
            m_fileMgr.download( finalImagePath, m_finalImage + m_imageExtension );
        }

        //  set up file manager / button listeners; 
        private function init () : void
        {           
            // add output container to stage at 0,0;
            addChildAt( m_output, 0 );

            // check to make sure stage is available ( which it wouldn't be if this class were instantiated from another class );
            if ( stage != null ) 
            {
                // set up stage;
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                // create image mask that matches the stage height & width;
                with ( m_mask.graphics )
                {
                    beginFill( 0x000000 );
                    drawRect( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
                }
            }

            // create progress indicator;
            with ( m_progress.graphics )
            {
                beginFill( 0x000000 );
                drawRect( 0, 0, upload.width, 1 );
            }

            addChild( m_progress );

            m_progress.x = upload.x;
            m_progress.y = upload.y + upload.height + 2;

            // set container to use as image capture area;
            captureContainer = m_output;

            // set capture container mask;
            captureContainer.mask = m_mask;

            // add effect to image;
            m_effect = new Scribble();

            captureContainer.addChild( m_effect );

            // show upload / scribble buttons;
            upload.show();

            // set progress bar to zero scale;
            m_progress.scaleX = 0;

            // set up file manager;
            m_fileMgr = new FileManager( uploadPath, m_uploadPath );
            m_fileMgr.addEventListener( FileManager.ON_PROGRESS, onUploadProgress );
            m_fileMgr.addEventListener( FileManager.ON_UPLOAD_ERROR, onUploadError );
            m_fileMgr.addEventListener( FileManager.ON_IMAGE_UPLOADED, onImageUploaded );

            // listen to buttons;
            upload.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onBrowse );

        // set up loader;
            m_downloader = new GraphicLoader();
            m_downloader.addEventListener( GraphicLoader.ON_LOAD_PROGRESS, onDownloadProgress );
            m_downloader.addEventListener( GraphicLoader.ON_LOAD_COMPLETE, onImageDownloaded );
            m_downloader.addEventListener( ErrorEvent.ERROR, onDownloadError );
        }

        //returns new string representing the month, day, hour, minute and millisecond of creation for use as the image name;   
        private function getUniqueName () : String
        {
            var d : Date = new Date();

            return d.getMonth() + 1 + '' + d.getDate() + '' + d.getHours() + '' + d.getMinutes() + ''  + d.getMilliseconds();
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I try to upload any movie I get this in the Output of flash:

```
image uploading : 1
ERROR: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2038: I/O FILE ERROR. URL: http://www.MYSITE.com/test/image.php?path=uploads/"]
```

So I do not know where is the error, I have set the permissions to 777 to all the files involved...

Comment: Just a wild guess. Check the error for 1 at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I took a look
  Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
That is not the case As i uploaded a 5Kb image and it didnt work...

Comment: Similar discussion with Error #2038 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545715/flex-error-2038-file-i-o-error

Comment: Also, the problem seems to be when using Firefox

Comment: I am using Chrome, and i have reviewed the url path, but it is ok....

Comment: You need to validate that the uploaded file is actually an image on the server side. Someone can ignore the flash and upload any file they want.

Comment: So I need to do this on php file, something like 
`$imgExtension = array('jpg','jpe','jpeg','gif','png');
$image_name = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$extension = strtolower($image_name['extension']);
if(in_array($extension,$ImgExtension)){
    //process file upload - move_uploaded_file()
}
`  would be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just give access right upload all in **FTP filezilla**  to that upload folder where you want upload this file.i think there is no access right to files...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found  what the error was, I debugged the php file and was getting an 500 internal error server, so checking the reason Ifound that, the permission was 777, so every one could write,  but my server just allow a self write, so I cdmod the file to 747 and it fixed the error.  Flash in the other hand when got the internal server error crashed together.